# clear all activities except one in android

Tags: android, android-activity

Below I'm showing the flow on how I want to navigate my `Activities`:

[image]

I tried writing the following code inside `D` and `E`:

```
Intent list = new Intent(AddComplaint.this, B.class);
list.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(list);
```

However, I'm facing two issues:

1. When `B` gets launched it shows a grey screen for a while, then it gets loaded.
2. When I go back from `B` it exits out of the application rather than going to `A` (the dashbord).

How can I fix this?

Comment: use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can achieve what you want by using [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP). If you send an Intent using this flag, it will be delivered to the existing Activity B, and any activities above B on the stack (C, D/E) will be finished.

Using [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK) will finish all previous activities on the stack, which would make B the only remaining activity - explaining why you exit the app when clicking back. Your grey background is unrelated to activity management and indicates the activity is simply taking a while to call onCreate().

Example code:

```
Intent list = new Intent(AddComplaint.this, B.class);
        list.setFlags
                (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(list);
```

Comment: it will reopen the activity B, Can we resume the Activity B?

Answer (score 0):

I think FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK is clearing all the activities from stack.

to go back from activity B to A again, without changing anything to your existing code , simple overrride onBackPress() method in activity B and startActivity A there.